# JS/jQ - Move horizontally across containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration

I have a series of DIV elements with more DIV elements inside of them, of variable lengths.  As example code to simplify the matter...

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="inset"></div>
 <div class="inset"></div>
 <div class="inset"></div>
 <div class="inset"></div>
 <div class="inset"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="inset"></div>
 <div class="inset"></div>
 <div class="inset"></div>
 <div class="inset"></div>
 <div class="inset"></div>
 <div class="inset"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="inset"></div>
 <div class="inset"></div>
 <div class="inset"></div>
</div>
```

I have been using jQuery's `each()` to move between the "inset" DIVs.  However, I've come to the realization I'm going to have to move between the first inset DIV in the first container, to the first in the second container, to the first in the third, then to the second in the first container, and so forth.

The problem is, I have no idea how to do this.

If it helps, the main purpose for moving these is to change their background colors in a preset pattern.  I do not believe it's possible to redo the structure of the code.

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: I don't funny understand what you are trying to do, can you mock up some sort of rough sketch so I can get a better idea of what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can, though my approach is not the most elegant.

Here's a sample (need to have Firebug installed to see the output): http://jsfiddle.net/ceZkr/

```
var maxlength = 0; // first need to find container with the most insets.
$('.container').each(function(index, val){
    var curlength = $(this).find('.inset').length;
    if(curlength > maxlength) {
        maxlength = curlength;
    }
});

console.log('our maxlength: ' + maxlength);

for(var i = 0;i<maxlength; i++) {
    $('.container').each(function(){
        var $box = $(this).find('.inset:eq('+i+')');
        if($box.length) {
            console.log( $box.text() );
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Or Chrome Developer Tools (ctrl-shift-i) or developer tools in IE (F12).  +1 for the answer though.

Comment: While the Fiddle works, for some reason I'm getting a whole lot of errors whenever I try to implement it into my code.  I'll try to get a more detailed example up later today.

Comment: Ahahahaha, works great, once I fixed my jQuery file (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882810/jquery-this-find-and-selector-this-not-working#comment-8191276) <_<.  Thanks again!